# Lodash - Get Value at Path with Default Values

Tags: javascript, object, lodash

Is there any way to get a value at a path with fallbacks to other paths should they not be defined?

```
var object = { a: 1 }

// Try to get d, fallback to e and then a
_.get(object, 'd', _.get(object, 'e', _.get(object, 'a')))
```

Is there a better method for this that i have missed?

Comment: Do you need to fallback strictly for undefined properties or  can they be false too? If you want to fallback for falsy values too you could do obj.d || obj.e || obj.f otherwise you can do a loop with object.hasOwnProperty and return the value for the first matching key that's defined.

Comment: Preferably only for undefined, but it's acceptable here to fallback for anything falsey. Looking for something more idiomatic than `obj.d || obj.e || obj.f `. Something like `_.pick`, but for picking a value, not picking keys.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Think I'm going for this but still want to see if anyone comes up with something better using lodash.

```
_.get(object, _.findKey(object, _.rearg(_.partial(_.includes, ['d', 'e', 'f']), 1)))
```

## Update

The above wont work if u want to find the keys for nested paths so back to:

```
_(object).at('b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a').compact().first()
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make your own helper method for this, perhaps something like this?

```
function pickValue(obj, keys, defaultValue) {
  var foundKey = keys.find(function(key) { return obj.hasOwnProperty(key); });
  return foundKey ? obj[foundKey] : defaultValue;
}
```

Usage:

```
var result = pickValue(obj, ['d', 'e', 'f'], 'default value');
```

Comment: Thanks :) But not keen on a mixin.

Comment: I just came up with `_.first(_.compact(_.at(object, 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a')))`

Comment: @JackTuck I think you can post that as an answer. Simply chain it, to make it more readable. e.g. `_(object).at('b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'a').compact().first()`

Comment: @ryeballar What do you think about my current answer? Bit less readable than ur chained version.